# SQL Server how to query max amount of active rentals per product per facility?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count of active rentals at any given time per product per facility. I also want the max number of active rentals that the facility ever had for each product.

An example:

1. Today Facility A has 6 active rentals for Product Z.
2. The most amount of active rentals that Facility A ever had for Product Z was 22.

It would be fantastic to get the result for both requests in the same result row but it's not necessary.

I have solved the first part but having problems with the second.
What I have so far for the second request:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ISNULL(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId)) AS Amount,
    ISNULL(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId) AS ProductID, 
    d.ProductName, 
    f.FacilityName
FROM  
    Rental r
INNER JOIN
    Product d ON (ISNULL(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId) = d.ProductId)
INNER JOIN
    Facility f ON r.FacilityId = f.FacilityId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Task t ON  (r.DeliveryTaskId = t.TaskId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    vEvent e ON (t.TaskId = e.TaskId) AND (t.CloseEventId = e.EventId)
WHERE
    (r.RentalStatusId = 2 OR r.RentalStatusId = 3) 
    AND (e.EventDate BETWEEN e.EventDate AND r.StopBillingDate)
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId), 
    d.ProductName, f.FacilityName
```

`RentalStatusId = 2` is for active rentals, `3` for closed. `e.EventDate` is the start rental date and `r.StopBillingDate` is the end rental date.

So I want to Max count of products with the same ProductID with the same FacilityID that at one point were within the range of start rental date and end rental date.

I Think I have to use a MAX function somewhere to get the max number of active rentals but it's just to confusing.

Comment: If you can create SQLFiddler with some records so that we can try. That would really help. http://sqlfiddle.com/ 
It is being hard to create Table, and sample records on ourside to find solution for your problem .

Answer (score 1):

I dont have SQL Server and your tables to test on my machine now. But I think you are looking to write sql something like :

```
Select TOP 1 T.ProductName, T.FacilityName, T.Amount from
   (
       --Your SubQuery to find the Sum of the Amount grouping by your Facility and Product
       Select ProductName, FacilityName, Count(*) as Amount
       From Your table, Joins
       Where Your Filters
       Group By Productname, FacilityName
   ) T
Order by T.Amount Desc
```

It is just to give you some idea, Im sorry for the inconvenience to write full solution.
Use the subquery to find the Summary data that would support your both context. And Use outer query to filter more and find exact solution using your Subquery result.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following query:

```
WITH cte_Rental_Calendar

    AS (
    SELECT CAST('2015-01-01'        AS DATE) AS dt

        UNION ALL

        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dy, +1, dt) AS DATE) AS dt

          FROM cte_Rental_Calendar

         WHERE dt < getdate()
         )
Select T.ProductName, T.FacilityName, Max(T.dt) as ByMonth, Max(T.rec_cnt) as MaxAmount from(
  SELECT c.dt
       , d.ProductName
       , f.FacilityName
       , Count(*) AS rec_cnt
    FROM            cte_Rental_Calendar c

    INNER JOIN      Rental              r

                 ON 1 = 1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN Task                t

                 ON r.DeliveryTaskId = t.TaskId

    LEFT OUTER JOIN vEvent              e

                 ON t.TaskId       = e.TaskId
                AND t.CloseEventId = e.EventId

    INNER JOIN      Product             d

                 ON isnull(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId) = d.ProductId

    INNER JOIN      Facility            f

                 ON r.FacilityId = f.FacilityId


   WHERE    c.dt between e.EventDate  and r.StopBillingDate and (r.RentalStatusId = 2 or r.RentalStatusId = 3 )
   GROUP BY c.dt
          , isnull(r.DeliveredProductId, r.OrderedProductId)
          , d.ProductName
          , f.FacilityName   ) T
          group by T.ProductName, T.FacilityName
          OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```